# How to check result from a jquery post?

Tags: jquery, post

HI I have one jquery POST function which I can't complete correctly can you help me ?

```
function submitlogin() {
    var form = document.login;
    var action = "chk_login";
    $.post("action.php", {
        action: action,
        user: form.user.value,
        pass: form.pass.value
    }, function(data) {
        if (data=="loginok")
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    );
}
```

The idea is that when my login form is submitted it get a check from action.php. 
My function submitlogin must return TRUE if user and pass are correct and FALSE if they are wrong.. Can you help me to clear my problem. Currently when I set alert(data) its comming out the text from the action.php so the connection is correct, my problem is only with getting the result TRUE or FALSE  from the post function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The callback from the ajax request does not care about the return value:

```
$.post("action.php", 
   {
       action: action, 
       user: form.user.value, 
       pass: form.pass.value
   }, 
   function(data)
  { 
      if(data=="loginok") 
          return true; 
      else 
          return false;
  });
```

When you say `return true` from your callback, there is nothing in the jQuery library inspecting that value. It looks like you're trying to basically do a form validation check when the button is pressed; you're confusing the event model with a synchronous call.

What is happening is this:

```
 -> Call to submitLogin();
     -> Invokes jQuery POST Ajax Method
     -> Immediately exits submitLogin

 -> When the POST request is complete, calls the callback
```

What you need to do, is probably something like this:

```
function submitlogin() 
{
    var form = document.login; var action = "chk_login";

    $.post("action.php", 
    {
        action: action, 
        user: form.user.value, 
        pass: form.pass.value
    }, 
    function(data)
    { 
        if(data == "loginok")
           $('#myForm').submit();
    });

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all `$.post` is asyn by nature so the function will not wait for it to return. Second thing is you are trying to return true/false from the post success handler which is wrong.

You can try using $.ajax with async false.

```
function submitlogin() {
    var form = document.login; var action = "chk_login";
    var returnVal = false;
        $.ajax({ 
           url: "action.php",
           async: false
           data: {action: action, user: form.user.value, pass:  form.pass.value},   
           success: function(data){ 
              returnVal = (data=="loginok"); 
           }
         });

    return returnVal; 
}
```